Для чего указывать качество параметром -crf, когда это делается битрейтом
ffmpeg -i tears_of_steel_1080p.webm -vf scale=640x360 -b:v 276k \
  -minrate 138k -maxrate 400k -tile-columns 1 -g 240 -threads 4 \
  -quality good -crf 36 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -c:a libopus \
  -pass 2 -speed 4 -y tos-640x360.webm

https://developers.google.com/media/vp9/settings/vod?hl=ru
Пример из гугла, вопрос в чем разница, зачем параметр -crf 36 когда указаны параметры -minrate 138k -b:v 276k -maxrate 400k
Разве они не одно и тоже роль играют? Меньше битрейт, хуже качество кадра. С -crf тоже самое, только если не ошибаюсь чем ниже он тем выше качество и наоборот.

crf - это альтернативный метод задания качества для однопроходного кодирования. При его указании будет меняться битрейт, а при указании битрейта - меняться crf. Вместе их мало смысла использовать.
